# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

whole code segment:

```
const Message= forwardRef(({ message,username}, ref)=> {
    const isUser = username === message.username;
    return (
            <div ref={ref} className={`message ${isUser && 'message__user'}`}>
                <Card className={isUser ? "message__userCard" : "message__guestCard"}>
                <CardContent >
                    <Typography 
                    color="black"
                    variant="h5"
                    component="h2"
                    >
                        {message.username}:{message.message}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                </Card>
            </div>
            
    )
});

export default Message;
```

error shows that the username part is undefined in this part.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

```
const isUser = username === message.username;
```

the parent where Message is called is

```
<FlipMove>
     {
       messages.map(({id , message}) => (
         <Message key={id} username={username} message={message}/> //Message.js component,passing the text to message component
       ))
     }
     </FlipMove>
```

Comment: Could you pls share the Parent Component from where Message is called?

Comment: Then `message` is `undefined`.  Do you have specific information indicating otherwise?

Comment: no , there's no other information, the username part is undefined .

Comment: @Shatakchhi: Well, to put it another way... If you have no information indicating that `message` should have a value then why do you expect it to have a value?  The error is pretty clear.  `message` is `undefined`.  So you can't dereference it.  You either need to provide a value for it when using this component or you need to check if it has a value before trying to use it.